# Scripts working during Unity Runtime in Editor, Not in Build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I've got this system up and running in, works perfectly in the editor, no errors, nothing. And of course, getting ready for release, I spin up a build, then, out of no-where it doesn't work, not at all. And the whole time the build is up and running, I'm getting the following error.

**NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at UnityEngine.Rendering.DebugManager.UpdateActions () [0x0001b] in C:\Users\harri\source\repos\The Lost Keep\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.render-pipelines.core@12.1.7\Runtime\Debugging\DebugManager.Actions.cs:244 at UnityEngine.Rendering.DebugUpdater.Update () [0x0002a] in C:\Users\harri\source\repos\The Lost Keep\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.render-pipelines.core@12.1.7\Runtime\Debugging\DebugUpdater.cs:180**

It doesn't appear to have any association with any scripts that I wrote, yet scripts I wrote just don't work.

Any tips on how to fix it?

Comment: I think this is the know longstanding issue that's still not fixed. Try adding a simple script where in the Awake() you call `DebugManager.instance.enableRuntimeUI = false;` and see if the problem disappears.

Answer (score 2):

Following [Bart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/488657/bart)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72531546/scripts-working-during-unity-runtime-in-editor-not-in-build/72645202#comment128127297_72531546) on the question

> I think this is the know longstanding issue that's still not fixed. Try adding a simple script where in the Awake() you call `DebugManager.instance.enableRuntimeUI = false;` and see if the problem disappears.

works for me.

Comment: Yea, that works. Just another of the Unity's skeletons...

Answer (score 0):

I received this error on iOS. In Unity Editor console all worked fine. Turned out that there was a new GameObject in the hierarchy list (at the bottom) called `[DebugUpdater]` with a script with the same name attached to it. The script is located in `Packages > Core RP Library > Runtime > Debugging > DebugUpdater`

I got rid of the object and things cleared up. Not sure how it showed up in the first place.